# python: line.startswith(str) will not work if the file contains the same string in every line

Tags: python

I have a file xyz.txt which has some values assigned to different variables like below.

```
abc.def = "Hi how are you"

abc.def.ghi = "Hi I am fine"

abc.def.ghi.jkl = "What are you doing"

abc.def.ghi.Mno = "I am working"
```

I want to write a python generic function which reads the line abc.def.ghi.Mno and changes the string from "I am working" to "I am playing"
This function should also be used for other files also. 
I tried with line.startswith(abc.def.ghi.Mno) but its not working.

Below is what I tried.

Thanks in advance.

```
def find_replace(new_value, start_str, filename):

result = ""

with open(filename) as f:

    for line in f:

        if line.lower().startswith( start_str ):

            list = line.split('=')

            list[1] = new_value + '\n'

            line = "=".join( list )

        result += line
f = open(filename, 'wt')

f.write(result)

f.close()


find_replace(new_value = "I am playing", start_str = "abc.def.ghi.Mno", filename=xyz.txt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it. You simply unnecessarily made `line` lowercase before testing if it starts with `"abc.def.ghi.Mno"`, a mixed-case string, so it naturally wouldn't be true. Remove `.lower()` and it should work.

Comment: Yeah it worked. It was my bad that I did not tried it. Thanks for the help blhsing :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your code. As blhsing mentioned, one is that line.startswith() is case sensitive, so calling .lower() will not match your start_str. You'll also want to make sure the filename is a string (add quotes). If you want to add the quotes back in as in your original xyz.txt, just escape them when you add the string add them to your list:

```
def find_replace(new_value, start_str, filename):

    result = ""
    with open(filename) as f:

        for line in f:

            if line.lower().startswith( start_str ):

                list = line.split('=')
                list[1] = "\"" + new_value + "\"\n"
                line = "=".join( list )

            result += line

    f = open(filename, 'wt')
    f.write(result)
    f.close()

find_replace(new_value = "I am playing", start_str = "abc.def.ghi.Mno", filename="xyz.txt")
```